# How to edit .java files from node_modules/react-native folder?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I need to solve a bug in react, but when I change the .java files in the node_modules/react-native folder I don't get any effect, I heard that there's a way to build from source, I followed the official tutorial https://reactnative.dev/contributing/how-to-build-from-source but it's not working, is there another way to change these files?

Comment: Are you aware that Java is a compiled language? Just editing the files is not going to do anything. Also it doesn't look like you have an issue editing files. It sounds like you have an issue building the project. And it is not working is not a question. Describe the issue you are having.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, yes it is possible to modify these react native java files, so much so that you can see in the link I attached, on the react page they teach you how to create your own distribution to do this, the problem is that the tutorial simply does not work, what I wanted to know is if there is another correct tutorial on how to do this procedure.

Comment: My interest is in solving these two bugs: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11068#issuecomment-1531450643 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25594#issuecomment -1453039216.  Which have been present for a long time and there was no interest from the community in solving them, so I migrated to Flutter due to stability, but I still need to fix these problems for the projects I already have in progress.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. All this additional context should be added to the question.